# How to remove the signature '## Evaluation Use only ##' in the docx4j pdf generation?

Tags: java, docx4j

```
     To remove the signature '## Evaluation Use only ##' from pdf generation using Docx4j.
```

Currently how the PDF document is generated - Using Template document, docx file will be created. From the created docx file, Docx file will be converted to PDF file format. In the generated PDF file, find this signature '## Evaluation Use only ##' in red color.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = 
WordprocessingMLPackage.load(initialStream);
MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
HashMap < String, String > variables = new HashMap < > ();
variables.put("name", "John Doe");
documentPart.variableReplace(variables);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
wordMLPackage.save(outputStream);
FileOutputStream outputSteam = new FileOutputStream("file1.pdf ");
Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, filestream);
```

code for reference for pdf generation.

Comment: a quick google reveals that it uses this converter https://converter-eval.plutext.com/ - so buy a license

Comment: Thanks Scary Wombat. Will buy a license.

Comment: You could try using apache fo